# Implementing this join in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join

I have 4 tables Position, Employee, Training and Trmatrix.

Table Position

```
PositionId   PosName      TrainingId
  1          developer     1,2,3
  2          Designer      4,5
  3          BDA           2,3,6
```

Table Employee

```
Employeeid    Ename       Posid   Courseid 
   1          Alex         1        4
   2          Shaun        2        1,2,3
   3          Hales        3
```

Table Training

```
Trainingid   Trainingname
  1            JAVA
  2            Dot Net
  3            PHP
  4            Photoshop
  5            JQUERY
  6            Client Handling
```

TrMatrix

```
TrmatId    TrID    empID
 1           1        1
 2           2        1
 3           3        1
 4           4        1
 5           4        2
 6           5        2
 7           1        2
 8           2        2
 9           2        3
 10          3        3
```

foreign Key relation
trmatrix trId corresponds to the trainingID of the trainingtable.
Employee posid corresponds to the PositionId of the Positiontable.
Employee courseId corresponds to the trainingId of the trianingtable.

BY basic Aim is to get that course/trainingname which is no present in the 
EMployee.Courseid column in correspondance to the trmatrix table,
which defines that I have to get the all entries from the trmatrix table for which there is no entry in the employee table Courseid column. 
Suppose in case of Alex I have to fetch all the data from the trmatrix table except for course 4 since it  is present in the courseid column of the Employee table, so it would return course no 1,2,3 not the no 4.
I am Newbie to the SQL so please help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What the TrMatrix table is is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: Which database are you using? There is no standard for stored procedures, so you'll get a different answer for nearly every RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should make PositionTraining and EmployeeCourse tables as well:

PositionTraining

```
PositionId   TrainingId
  1          1
  1          2
  1          3
  2          4
  2          5
  3          2
  3          3
  3          6
```

EmployeeCourse

```
Employeeid    Courseid 
   1          4
   2          1
   2          2
   3          3
```

and then remove `Position.TrainingId` and `Employee.Courseid`.

By doing this you make the data much easier to query.

Answer (score 1):

To get things which are not present in one table from another you can use

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT value FROM OtherTable)
```

or

```
WHERE NOT IN (SELECT value FROM OtherTable)
```

However there is a class of queries called subqueries and these are very useful in this circumstance and a very good article on them is here
http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html
 (its written for ms access but the synstax and MS SQL rules are exactly the same so dont be put off)

Comment: Ian P Thanks for the reply. I tried out this NOT EXIST clause but please let me know how to check the comma seperated column value(courseid in employee) with the one having the single value(trId trmatrix).

Comment: Hi Kushal, that is really why you should have employee course in its own table. You can create a user defined function to split these out to a table (answer UDF for splitting out entries), the core of what you want is in the the other answer I'm about to post, but things get messy! If you have not got a lot of courses then you can manually load the table. The real lesson here is that a table should consist of rows, each with singular values and not mutiple values either conconated as delimited strings or in mutiple columns (google SQL table Normalisation) it is largly what SQL is about

Answer (score 0):

UDF for spliting out entries

```
Create function [dbo].[atf_BarListToTable]
    (@list ntext)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (ListPosn int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                          SString  VARCHAR(1028) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos int
    DECLARE @textpos int
    DECLARE @ChunkLength smallint
    DECLARE @str nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @tmpstr nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @leftover nvarchar(4000)
    SET @textpos = 1
    SET @leftover = ''
    WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
    BEGIN
        SET @ChunkLength = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2
        SET @tmpstr = ltrim(@leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @ChunkLength))
        SET @textpos = @textpos + @ChunkLength
        SET @pos = charindex('|', @tmpstr)
        WHILE @pos > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @str = substring(@tmpstr, 1, @pos - 1)
                INSERT @tbl (SString) VALUES( @str)
                SET @tmpstr = ltrim(substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr)))
                SET @pos = charindex('|', @tmpstr)
            END
        SET @leftover = @tmpstr
    END
    IF ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)) <> ''
        INSERT @tbl (SString) VALUES(@leftover)
    RETURN
END
```